# SwapBuffer Nvidia Crash

Tags: windows, winapi, opengl

EDIT: I thought this was restricted to Attribute-Created GL contexts, but it isn't, so I rewrote the post.

Hey guys, whenever I call `SwapBuffers(hDC)`, I get a crash. If I create it with `WGL_CONTEXT_DEBUG_BIT_ARB`, I get a

> Too many posts were made to a semaphore.

from Windows as I call `SwapBuffers`. What could be the cause of this?

Update: No crash occurs if I don't draw, just clear and swap.

Here's a bit of the code with the irrelevant bits cut out:

```
static  PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd =             // pfd Tells Windows How We Want Things To Be
    {
        sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),              // Size Of This Pixel Format Descriptor
        1,                                          // Version Number
        PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW |                        // Format Must Support Window
        PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL |                        // Format Must Support OpenGL
        PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,                           // Must Support Double Buffering
        PFD_TYPE_RGBA,                              // Request An RGBA Format
        32,                                         // Select Our Color Depth
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                           // Color Bits Ignored
        0,                                          // No Alpha Buffer
        0,                                          // Shift Bit Ignored
        0,                                          // No Accumulation Buffer
        0, 0, 0, 0,                                 // Accumulation Bits Ignored
        24,                                         // 24Bit Z-Buffer (Depth Buffer)  
        0,                                          // No Stencil Buffer
        0,                                          // No Auxiliary Buffer
        PFD_MAIN_PLANE,                             // Main Drawing Layer
        0,                                          // Reserved
        0, 0, 0                                     // Layer Masks Ignored
    };

if (!(hDC = GetDC(windowHandle)))
    return false;

unsigned int PixelFormat;
if (!(PixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(hDC, &pfd)))
    return false;

if (!SetPixelFormat(hDC, PixelFormat, &pfd))
    return false;

hRC = wglCreateContext(hDC);
if (!hRC) {
    std::cout << "wglCreateContext Failed!\n";
    return false;
}

if (wglMakeCurrent(hDC, hRC) == NULL) {
    std::cout << "Make Context Current Second Failed!\n";
    return false;
}

... // OGL Buffer Initialization

glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glUseProgram(myprogram);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indexCount, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (void *)indexStart);
SwapBuffers(GetDC(window_handle));
```

Comment: Post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @BDL Done. It's difficult because the codebase is massive and I'm not exactly sure what could cause the error. If this is relevant, I DO get a GL_VALIDATE_STATUS as false but without an info log. GL_LINK_STATUS returns true though.

Comment: You should call `SwapBuffers` using the HDC that you passed to 'wglMakecurrent'.

Comment: @ChrisBecke Just tried it, still get issues.

Comment: *"Crash"* is a fairly fuzzy problem description. It's the catch-all phrase people use for pretty much any type of error they cannot interpret, ranging from debug output and failed assertions to unhandled exceptions and process termination. Please be more explicit in describing your issue.

Comment: @IInspectable The program freezes, screen goes black, and then I get a fatal error called in Visual Studio from Nvidia's DLL.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. The SwapBuffer(hDC) command was simply where the error occurred, but did not have anything to do with it. I believe my error was due to something related to my indices, as if I draw only the first mesh in the model,  everything works as intended. Nvidia crashed with this error, Intel went on and disregarded it.

Nonetheless, thank you to Chris Becke for pointing out a future memory leak using GetDC(hwnd).